# Using and on shorthand if

Tags: javascript

Basically I want to do this:

```
x ? console.log("true") : x=55 && console.log("changed!!")
```

Where if `x` is `false` it will change the value to `55` and `console.log` "change!!"

Comment: The question is about how it can be done, not if it is a good practice or not

Comment: @graciano right, and I'm leaving a comment for clarification. [The XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) is running rampant in these parts, so *just* answering the question doesn't always fix the real problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example code, the [assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) is going to evaluate the entire right hand operand of the expression which in this case is `55 && console.log("changed!!")`. Since `55` is truthy it will then continue to evaluate `console.log` which will always return `undefined`. The returned `undefined` is then ultimately assigned to `x`.

```js
var x = false;

x ? console.log("true") : x = 55 && console.log("changed!!");

console.log({x});
```

You could use the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) and parens to group the command correctly as below to accomplish what you want to do.

```js
var x = false;

x ? console.log("true") : (x = 55, console.log("changed!!"));

console.log({x});
```

The reason for using the comma operator rather than simply grouping the expression as `(x = 55) && console.log("changed!!")` is that the comma operator is specifically intended for use cases like this. From MDN's documentation:

> ...use the comma operator when you want to include multiple expressions in a location that requires a single expression.

As a final note, I would be hesitant to use a [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) as a shorthand for a conditional statement as in this case since the resultant of the ternary is discarded. It is generally considered to be more readable for a developer later on (including yourself) to read it as a conditional statement so they know explicitly what the intention is.

```js
if (x) {
  console.log("true");
} else {
  x = 55;
  console.log("changed!!");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. That makes sense.
By the way, how did you include snippets in the comments?

Comment: @AnthonyWhite First, I'm glad you found it helpful. Second, in the text entry area there is a button in the toolbar along the top that will open an overlay that allows you to include JS, HTML, and CSS. It is the last button in the second grouping of buttons from the left. It looks like a page with `<>` on it. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you basically want to run several instructions in a ternary operator ?

The right way to do this is to use parenthesis and commas:

```
x ? console.log("true") : (x=55, console.log("changed!!"));
```

But if you are just testing a boolean variable, go for a if statement, it will make your code way more readable for everybody:

```
if (x) {
    console.log("true");
}
else {
    x = 55;
    console.log("changed!!");
}
```

This seems way more natural and human-friendly

Answer (score 1):

Because ternaries always need to return somehting, you need to wrap your console.log in a function.

```
let x = 0;
return x != 55 ?
return function() {
console.log("true")
} :
return function() {
 console.log("changed!!");
x = 55;
};
```

Comment: That wouldn't EXECUTE the function, though, so you never get the logs or the assignments.

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet is correct, but you just need parenthesis. What you are doing now is:

```
x ? console.log("true") : x = (55 && console.log("changed!!"))
```

So you are assigning `x` to the return value of `console.log`

A parenthesis is enough to have the correct behaviour:

```
x ? console.log("true") : (x=55) && console.log("changed!!")
```

Comment: Yes, but if you add parenthesis then you don't care of the value of `console.log()`

Answer (score 0):

You need some parethesis to prevent operator precedence of `&&` over the following expression.

```js
var x = false;

x ? console.log("true") : (x = 55) && console.log("changed!!")

console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `||`. The attribution `x=55` is truthy so it never gets to your console.log

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  x? console.log("true") : (x=55, console.log("changed!!"))
```

Comment: you have to use a comma between the two statements instead of a semi-colon